# how does this lambda work?

Tags: python, lambda

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
message = filter(lambda x: x != "X",garbled)
print message

I am another secret message!
```

How in the world does this work ? help me understand

```
list = range(1,101)    
print filter(lambda x:x>30 and x<70, list)

[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
```

I understand how this works , but not the first one.

Comment: It filters out any character that's `X`...!?

Comment: I think the source of your confusion is maybe that you don't realize that strings can be iterated over in Python in exactly the same way as lists can. Try running: `for character in "Hello": print(character)` and see what you get ;-)

Comment: @deceze shouldn't it be checking if the first element IXXX != X and so on, then return empty set?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I see. It goes letter by letter rather than word by word. I get it now.

Comment: It prints every char from `garbled` except `X`s.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker would you like to write the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you *do* understand the second example, but *not* the first example that is effectively identical, I think the source of your confusion is that you don't realize that strings can be iterated over in Python in exactly the same way as lists can.

Here's a simple example:

```
>>> for character in 'Hello': print('->', character, '<-')
... 
-> H <-
-> e <-
-> l <-
-> l <-
-> o <-
```

Think of strings in Python as a "string of characters" or a "list of characters" (the difference being that strings are immutable, to "tuple of characters" would actually be more appropriate, but doesn't sound as nice).

See the [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) for more information.

Whether this is a *feature* or a *bug* is somewhat controversial in the Python community, by the way, and many people proposed to change this for Python 3. The problem is that this can really bite you, consider:

```
def my_function(list_expected):
    for item in list:
        do_something(item)
```

This is a common enough pattern, and you're expected to call it as `my_function(['Hello', 'World']).

But what if I forgot that this function expects a list? And I call it as `my_function('Hello')`? Depending on what `do_something(item)` does, you either get an error or some subtly wrong behaviour. Be on the lookout for this.

Personally, I don't like this Python feature much and would have preferred to loop *explicitly*...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to break it down a bit. First you have [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) which takes a function and an iterable and applies the function to each element in the iterable and drops anything the function returns `False` for.

In this case the function is the lambda which is just `x != "X"` which is equivalent to:

```
def foo(x):
    return x != "X"
```

so any element in the iterable, which in this case is your input string `garbled`, that is equal to "X" will get removed.